# How to omit the character $ when entering a path stored in a variable?

Tags: bash, variable, cd-command

I have a frequently used directory. Suppose it is:

```
/etc/insserv.conf.d/testname
```

I set a variable in my `/root/.bashrc`:

```
mydir=/etc/insserv.conf.d/testname
```

Now, I can open this directory by this command

```
cd $mydir
```

But I really don't like that character `$`. Is there any workaround can implement this? I mean: I want to open this directory just by `cd mydir`, is it possible in `Ubuntu 16.04`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for `cdable_vars` option. To activate it run `shopt -s cdable_vars` if you are using bash (`setopt cdablevars` in case of zsh). After that simple `cd mydir` would work.

**Note** that if you try to `cd mydir` from a directory which contains a file or directory by the same name, then the shell will attempt to use the file or directory object in the current directory, instead of expanding the variable.

Comment: Thanks very much,that is work..And can I forbid [that output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0K149.png) of the command?

Comment: @yode, I don't think bash has any option to disable that, but you can always redirect the output to the black hole: `alias cd='cd >/dev/null'`

Answer (score 5):

How about just:

```
mydir
```

Just define the variable as you have already done and create a function:

```
mydir=/etc/insserv.conf.d/testname
mydir(){ cd "$mydir"; }
```

Done.

An alternative is to use an alias:

```
alias mydir='cd "$mydir"'
```

Comment: Anyway,thaks a lot.And actually it is my current method.But I just want to use `cd mydir` in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a global alias.
It does'nt seem to bash does support it, but it works very well with zsh.

### Demo

[image: <code>% alias -g asd="bsd"; echo asd</code> -> <code>bsd</code>]

### Installation

```
$ sudo apt install zsh
```

To get the same look as mine, you should

- Install Oh My Zsh:

  ```
  sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
  ```
- Replace your theme to agnoster:

  ```
  sed 's/^ZSH_THEME=".*"$/ZSH_THEME="agnoster"/' -i .zshrc
  ```
- And install Powerline fonts to make agnoster working:

  ```
  curl https://pastebin.com/raw/nD4DTpuF | bash
  ```
- Install the syntax highlighting plugin:

  - Download

    ```
    git clone git://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git .oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting
    ```
  - And apply:

    ```
    sed 's/^plugins=\((.*)\)$/plugins=(\1 zsh-syntax-highlighting)'
    ```
  - Finally, reload your configuration settings:

    ```
    source .zshrc
    ```

Sorry for this long tutorial, but I hope, you will love it.

Comment: Thanks very much,and could I know your value of `echo $PS1`?

Comment: @yode

$PS1: `%{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)`

$(build_prompt): `%{%K{black}%}%{%F{default}%} %(!.%{%F{yellow}%}.)led@%m %{%K{blue}%F{black}%}%{%F{black}%} %~ %{%K{yellow}%F{blue}%}%{%F{black}%}  home ● %{%k%F{yellow}%}%{%f%}`

But you should install a powerline patched font to make it display correctly.